# RMAN backups error while creating full & incremental backups

Tags: oracle, database-backups, rman

We have our oracle instance running on windows server & when configured RMAN to take the backups we are seeing following error in the logs,

**Error Details:**

```
channel ch1: starting piece 1 at 07-MAY-17
channel ch1: finished piece 1 at 07-MAY-17
piece handle=\\backup_share\FULL_db01_20170507.BAK tag=COMPLETE_BACKUP comment=NONE
channel ch1: backup set complete, elapsed time: 02:10:37
channel ch1: starting incremental level 0 datafile backup set
channel ch1: specifying datafile(s) in backup set
including current control file in backup set
including current SPFILE in backup set
channel ch1: starting piece 1 at 07-MAY-17
released channel: ch1
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on ch1 channel at 05/07/2017 23:10:45
ORA-19504: failed to create file "\\backup_share\FULL_db01_20170507.BAK"
ORA-27038: created file already exists
OSD-04010: <create> option specified, file already exists
```

**RMAN Command Script:**

```
run{ 
Allocate channel ch1 type disk format '\\backup_share\full_%d_%T.bak'; 
Backup incremental level=0 database tag='complete_backup'; 
Release channel ch1; 
Allocate channel t1 type disk format '\\backup_share\ctrl_%d_%T'; 
Backup current controlfile; 
Release channel t1; 
}
```

I see same kind of logging when trying to take incremental backups. Could someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> [oracle@orcluat ~]$ oerr ora 27038
> 27038, 00000, "created file already exists"
> // *Cause:  trying to create a database file, but file by that name already
> //          exists
> // *Action: verify that name is correct, specify reuse if necessary
> ```

`%d` format specifies the name of the database and `%T` specifies the year, month, and day in the Gregorian calendar in this format: `YYYYMMDD`. It is also being reflected  in your backup file name, `FULL_db01_20170507.BAK`. There might have files with the same name.

Better to use `%U` in your file name format which specifies a system-generated unique filename.

**Documentation:**

[formatSpec](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/backup.111/b28273/rcmsubcl010.htm#RCMRF195)